# Jquery FormData can append array to upload on net core?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I writed this code to upload file using Jquery

and I ready a model to maaping this ajax return

```
$("input[name='ResolutionAttachedFile']")
            .each(function () {
                var ReadyToUpload = $(this)[0].files;
                if (ReadyToUpload.length > 0) {
                    $.each(ReadyToUpload, function (i, file) {
                        data.append("ResolutionAttachedFile", file);
                    });
                }
            });

        test.append('MyIFormFile', data);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/Home/DocumentPage',
            data: test,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

and this is my controller and data model

```
public class test
{ 
   public testArea MyIFormFile { get; set; }
   public class testArea
   {
       public List<IFormFile> ResolutionAttachedFile { get; set; }
   }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DocumentPage(test _test)
{
    return View();
}
```

but this model can't mapping value.

and I don't want to change model structure.

so how can I do let it can working?

Comment: could you log the test in your browser console just before sending the request and share the result

Comment: You have not told us what `data` or `test` is or where they are declared. But to bind to that model you would need `yourFormData.append('MyIFormFile.ResolutionAttachedFile[0]', someValue)` (i.e. the fully qualified name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For binding to `MyIFormFile.ResolutionAttachedFile`, you need to pass with `MyIFormFile.ResolutionAttachedFile`.

Make a test with ajax below:

```
    <div>
    <input type="file" multiple name="ResolutionAttachedFile" />
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("input[name='ResolutionAttachedFile']")
            .change(function () {
                var data = new FormData();

                $("input[name='ResolutionAttachedFile']").each(function () {
                    var ReadyToUpload = $(this)[0].files;
                    if (ReadyToUpload.length > 0) {
                        $.each(ReadyToUpload, function (i, file) {
                            data.append("MyIFormFile.ResolutionAttachedFile", file);
                        });
                    }
                });
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '/DocumentPage',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

            });

    </script>
}
```

**Note**

As my test, it will fail when the project is under `netcoreapp2.1`, it fail to bind when there is no extra properties in `testArea`. It only works when there is additionl properties like `Name` and set the name value from ajax.

For resolving this issue, you could migrate your project to `netcoreapp2.2`.

Here is my working `.csproj`

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  <UserSecretsId>aspnet-IdentityCore-85ED30A8-40E9-4BD5-A9D2-EAF6BCF0D5F1</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0-preview3-35497" PrivateAssets="All" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.5" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```